# how to resolve long attribute value in a table

Tags: database, database-design

Just a simple question, say I have a table and one of their attributes is jobs... the job options can be from 0-20 characters (varchar(20))... is this okay or should I create a mapping table so that a = job1, b = job2, ..etc..etc, so when I insert to the database, I insert it as an 'a' instead of job 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but I would let the Jobs lookup table use an integer as the primary key instead of a, b, c, etc.

This way you can give the users a combo box or a list box to enter this value (They see the long name and not the number/key).

Also, from an administrative perspective you can let someone just enter more Jobs in the Jobs table and they will be available without any special coding.

You will have to join these tables anytime you want to link the full job description.

Comment: so when inserting to the table, I would just insert an integer to represent a job description? and when I want to show data to users I'd need to join the two tables to get the full job description?

Comment: Yes. It is a good way of avoiding spelling problems, duplicates and other common errors.